# My Winter Bash icon is missing

Tags: support, bug, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The Winter Bash icon is missing as with the hat's I earned. I have earned two hats, including one which come with the silver badge, It was there, and I was using it also. But now when I log in it's not there. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

As you can see above there is not **a hat or Winter Bash icon**.

I am using **macOS v10.13 (High Sierra)** and my browser is **Chrome version 63.0.3239.84 (official build) (64-bit)**.

Comment: Of course no i loved it, I am using **Mac OS High Sierra** and my browser is *Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: It's the same underlying issue, that's why it's a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Mureinik: this question is a duplicate, as it is the exact same issue.